Getting `-1 Unknown Status Code` & `ContentType: null` in Ktor
Below is the response log which I get sometimes while calling API.
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  HttpClient: RESPONSE: -1 Unknown Status Code
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  FROM: https://webservice.azurewebsites.net/en/Dispatch/getTickets
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  COMMON HEADERS
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> content-length: 0
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 07:42:23 GMT
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> set-cookie: ARRAffinity=6dec0997e21dec30ce7ef102ebaec80934d28e2723296e23b047a25a64c195a9;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=webservice.azurewebsites.net; ARRAffinitySameSite=6dec0997e21dec30ce7ef102ebaec80934d28e2723296e23b047a25a64c195a9;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=webservice.azurewebsites.net
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at '09/25/2024 07:22:35'"
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> x-android-received-millis: 1727250143135
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> x-android-response-source: NETWORK 401
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> x-android-selected-protocol: http/1.1
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> x-android-sent-millis: 1727250142738
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  -> x-powered-by: ASP.NET
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  BODY Content-Type: null
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  BODY START
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  
13:12:23.142 System.out               I  BODY END

Getting below crash log after this.
Expected response body of the type 'class app.models.Response' but was 'class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel'
In response from `https://webservice.azurewebsites.net/en/Dispatch/getTickets`
Response status `-1 Unknown Status Code`
Response header `ContentType: null` 
Request header `Accept: application/json`
                                         
You can read how to resolve NoTransformationFoundException at FAQ: 
https://ktor.io/docs/faq.html#no-transformation-found-exception
io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: Expected response body of the type 'class app.models.Response' but was 'class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel'

In response from `https://webservice.azurewebsites.net/en/Dispatch/getTickets`
Response status `-1 Unknown Status Code`
Response header `ContentType: null` 
Request header `Accept: application/json`
                                         
You can read how to resolve NoTransformationFoundException at FAQ: 
https://ktor.io/docs/faq.html#no-transformation-found-exception
at io.ktor.client.call.HttpClientCall.bodyNullable(HttpClientCall.kt:94)
at app.service.WebService$DispatchService.getTickets(WebService.kt:1088)
at app.service.WebService$DispatchService$getTickets$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

It is not coming due to token expire. I have tried to reset token as below by manually handling the -1 status code. But issue not solved.
ResponseObserver { response ->
                if (response.status.value == -1 && response.contentType() == null ) {
                    resetToken()
                }
            }

It is only fixed after restarting the android app. How to fix this in runtime? Any help would be appreciated.

What authentication mechanism does the client use? Do you use the Auth client plugin? Is it expected that the server sends a -1 status code?

Yes, I am using Auth client plugin and Bearer authentication mechanism. There is no chance of server sending -1 status code.
